# Capturing video from ip camera that really work

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, dll, video-streaming

I'm trying for days create the simple JFrame with transmit of images from camera ip.

I tried following the examples listed below, but unsuccessful.

http://blog.rolandopalermo.com/2012/03/camara-ip-cam-java.html

[capturing video from ip camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186105/capturing-video-from-ip-camera/)

For see the image from camera, I used public camera ip available online :

http://plazacam.studentaffairs.duke.edu/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=784040

someone could help me in this examples or provide an example of code source that really work  an library appropriate ?

Thanks!